# Solving a second order non-autonomous difference equation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. Let us consider the following second order non-autonomous difference equation:
$$u_{n+1}-(r^{2n+1}+1)u_{n}+r^{2n-1}u_{n-1}=d_{n}$$ where $d_{n}$ is real sequence.

How I can solve this equation with respect to $u_{n}$. I am not able to find the good idea.

Comment: Do we know anything about $d_n$ (except it being a real sequence)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u_n=r^{n^2}v_n$, then $r^{(n+1)^2}(v_{n+1}-v_n)-r^{n^2}(v_n-v_{n-1})=d_n$, so $$v_n-v_{n-1}=r^{-n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n d_n$$
$$u_n=r^{n^2}v_n=r^{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^nr^{-j^2}\sum_{i=1}^jd_j$$

Comment: @ Michael: Where is the dependence on the initial condition!

Comment: $u_n=r^{n^2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\left(r^{-j^2}(\sum_{i=1}^jd_j)+a\right)+b\right)$